# Slider not coming in Static home page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress' [Optimizer theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/optimizer/). I want to create a static home page with only the slider in it but after I update the Home page with Homepage template, the slider won't show on it.

Here is the code of slider shown in header.php

```
<!--Slider START-->
    <?php if (is_home() && is_front_page()) { ?>

        <div id="slidera" class="layer_wrapper <?php if(!empty($optimizer['hide_mob_slide'])){ echo 'mobile_hide_slide';} ?>">
            <?php $slidertype = $optimizer['slider_type_id']; ?>
            <?php get_template_part('frontpage/slider',''.$slidertype.''); ?>
        </div> 

      <?php } ?> 
  <!--Slider END-->
```

and here is the template coding

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/

global $optimizer;
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
<div class="home_wrap layer_wrapper">
<div class="fixed_wrap fixindex">
            <!--FRONTPAGE WIDGET AREA-->
            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'front_sidebar' ) ) : ?>
                <div id="frontsidebar" class="frontpage_sidebar">       
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'front_sidebar' ); ?>
                 </div> 
            <?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div><!--layer_wrapper class END-->

<?php }else{ ?>

<div class="fixed_site">
<div class="fixed_wrap fixindex">
    <?php get_template_part('template_parts/post','layout4'); ?> 
</div>
</div>

<?php } //is_front_page ENDS ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the id condition...

```
<?php if (is_front_page() || is_page('put your page id here')) { ?>
    <div id="slidera" class="layer_wrapper <?php if(!empty($optimizer['hide_mob_slide'])){ echo 'mobile_hide_slide';} ?>">
        <?php $slidertype = $optimizer['slider_type_id']; ?>
        <?php get_template_part('frontpage/slider',''.$slidertype.''); ?>
    </div> 

  <?php } ?>
```

if you want you can remove OR condition form if